# How can I read asynchronously from an inputstream?

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous, inputstream

I have a Socket with its input ad output stream. I want to use output synchronously and input asynchronously and store everything received without blocking the input.

```
Socket socket;
BufferedOutputStream outToServer;
DataInputStream inFromServer;
List<byte[]> incoming=ArrayList<byte[]>();


socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",9100), 5000);
outToServer = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
inFromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

How can I add an input listener to fill incoming list with incoming data?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to look into the java.nio packages. There is full support for doing "async", "non-blocking IO" with standard java ... since quite some years.

See [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2853780/core-java/socket-programming-for-scalable-systems.html) for some examples. That tutorial basically starts with code as you have written in your question ... to transform that into "async".

But to be precise: you don't need to use "nio" or "nio2"; but if you are serious about turning into that direction, then nio/nio2 provide extremely helpful features.

Comment: Ok, but can I differentiate and use sync write and async read?

Comment: There is an example with nio for server side but not for client side...

Comment: And you think for async reading or writing to a stream it matters if that stream is used on a server or a client?

Comment: No but I need to find how to open the connection, however I will search for other examples

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to read InputStream asynchronously. You have to go where this InputStream is created, and access the source of data explicetly.

Answer (score -1):

You need only to pass the `InputStream` to the `Runnable` that need to be executed asynchronously. This can be done for example in the constructor.

```
public class ConsumeInput implements Runnable {
    private InputStream inputStream;

    public ConsumInput(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Do something with inputStream
    }

}
```

And in the main thread

```
...
ConsumeInput consumeInput = new ConsumeInput(inFromServer);
Thread t = new Thread(consumeInput);
t.start();
```

Obviously you can also use the new api to handle threads.

Note: this is only a skeleton code. You need to handle exceptions and closure of streams.

Comment: what should I put into run()? I have to put read content into List<byte[]> incoming, but how can I block the loop waiting for new content?

Comment: You need to put in the run method exactly the same code that you will use in the main thread to read the data.

Comment: In the main thread now I'm reading only what I need (4bytes) and then I discard everything, but now I have to consume everything received from its inputstream otherwise the sender will hold waiting for free sending buffer.
The best option would be an event listener that fires a method when data is available.

Comment: This is still blocking if you did inputStream.read in run method.